# cURL GET topspin API - PHP

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm trying to interact with the topspin API in PHP.

On their website:

```
curl --data "auth_token=abc123&email=test@example.com&account_id=1&
acquired_by=curltest" http://api.artistlink.com/home/fans.json
```

How to do I do this in PHP?

I've tried something like this:

```
$str= "?auth_token=blah&email=blah@blah.com&account_id=1&
acquired_by=curltest";

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.artistlink.com/home/fans.json'.$str);      curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I get this:
[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Try this:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.artistlink.com/home/fans.json');
    $data = "auth_token=blah&email=blah@blah.com&account_id=1&acquired_by=curltest";        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Check out some more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `HTTP_GET` instead of `HTTP_POST` Try:

```
$str = "auth_token=blah&email=blah@blah.com&account_id=1&acquired_by=curltest";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.artistlink.com/home/fans.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($data);
if (isset($json->error)) {
    echo $json->error;
} else {
    print_r($json);
}
```